# SQL statement, how to join an id on a list of ids in sqlite3

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

First off I'm very new to SQL, so the implementation might not be conventional :)
I'm using `sqlite3` and `pandas` and am trying to link two tables (Devices and Tests) with a join statement. I would like query all the devices associated with Test_1 without knowing its name, id or how many devices there are. For example with an SQL query that goes something like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM Tests
JOIN Device ON Devices.id = Tests.Device_ids
WHERE Devices.name = 'Device_1'"
```

The problem I'm having is, that I need multiple Devices to perform a test. As I use `pandas` `dataFrame.to_sql()` and `sqlite3` the only options (as I see it) are to store the Device ids either as a string of a list (option 1) or as entries with the same id (option 2).

```
Devices               Tests (Option 1)                  Tests (Option 2)

| id | Name     |     | id | Name   | Device_ids  |     | id | Name   | Device_ids  |
|  1 | Device_1 |     |  1 | Test_1 | '[1, 3]'    |     |  1 | Test_1 | 1           |
|  2 | Device_2 |     |  2 | Test_2 | '[2, 3]'    |     |  1 | Test_1 | 3           |      
|  3 | Device_3 |                                       |  2 | Test_2 | 2           |
                                                        |  2 | Test_2 | 3           |
```

Option 1: doesn't work so far but would be preferred

Option 2: doesn't return Device_3 as part of Test_1

I already have a running environment which works similar to the one above so I can not really change the implementation.
Here some code to clarify what I'd like to do:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

tests = {'id':[1,2], 'name':['test_1', 'test_2'], 'device_ids':['[1,3]','[2,3]']}
tests = pd.DataFrame(tests)
print(tests)
tests.to_sql('tests', con)


devices = {'id':[1,2,3], 'name':['Device_1', 'Device_2', 'Device_3']}
devices = pd.DataFrame(devices)
print(devices)
devices.to_sql('devices', con)

query = "SELECT * FROM tests JOIN devices ON devices.id = tests.device_ids WHERE devices.name = 'Device_1'"
pd.read_sql_query(query, con)
```

The output I'm looking for is:

```
| id | Name   | Device_ids  |    
|  1 | Test_1 | '[1, 3]'    |
```

Comment: you can replace [INNER ]`JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: *Option 2: doesn't return Device_3 as part of Test_1* your query is searching for 'Device_1' not 'Device_3'. Clarify what you want.

Comment: You failed to clearly state what are your inputs and what are the expected outputs. Furthermore, the initial SQL query is incorrect because is selects from `Tests`, joins on `Tests` (again), and later use a non referenced table `Devices`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the correct way to use joined queries in SQL is to have one single data per row. This means that the only available option is 2. But you can easily convert from your code using `explode`:

```
...
tests = {'id':[1,2], 'name':['test_1', 'test_2'], 'device_ids':[[1,3],[2,3]]}
tests = pd.DataFrame(tests).explode('device_ids')
print(tests)
tests.to_sql('tests', con)
...
```

Then to get the devices required for a test, you can use:

```
con.execute("""SELECT devices.* FROM devices
JOIN tests ON tests.device_ids = devices.id
WHERE tests.name = ?""", ('test_1',)).fetchall()
```

it give as expected:

```
[(0, 1, 'Device_1'), (2, 3, 'Device_3')]
```